# Check if field contains numbers, wrap the numbers with container and class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you have something simple like this in HTML:

```
<div class="main">Item 7,000</div>
```

How to make javascript apply an html element and a class for the `7,000` part (because its numeric) on page load? To something like this:

```
<div class="main">Item <span class="wrap">7,000</span></div>
```

Or maybe just an html element, if with class not possible.

I apologies I don't have any code to share right now. I'm still browsing other questions.

Maybe it should be something with jQuery if `$.isNumeric()` is `true` then apply element?

Comment: the 7,000 will actually be a string

Comment: do you have constant pattern `Item 7,000`?

Comment: @Omi All numbers will contain same format `text 123,456` etc. It will include a comma.

Comment: is item ll remains same in all cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be edge case but accomplishes your goal

```js
$(function () {
  $(".main").each(function (index, element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var wrapped = $element.text().replace(/(.+?)((\d{1,3},?)+)/g, '$1<span class="wrap">$2</span>');
    $element.html(wrapped);
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">Item 7,000</div>
<div class="main">Item 960</div>
<div class="main">Item 7,000,000</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript regex find a matching number and replace with span

```
var regex =/\b(\d+)\b/g
```

```js
var regex =/\b(\d+)\b/g

var text = document.getElementById("main").innerHTML;
  
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = text.replace(regex,'<span class="wrap">$1</span>')
```

```css
span.wrap{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<p id="main">Item : 7000</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `node.textContent` you can get the string inside the div

`string = document.querySelector('#main').textContent // --> "Item 7,000"`

From here you can use Array#split to separate each word:

`array = string.split(' '); --> ['Item','7,000']`

Now remove the comma and check `isNaN` for each, return an array w:

`newNode = array.map((e)=> isNaN(e.replace(/,/g,"")) ? e : {element:'span', content: e})`

Now you have `['Item', { element: 'span', content: '7,000'}]` which you can use to generate the contents of the `div` element in your example...

There might be way better ways to do this, I am just trying to help :)